# Why an update sql statement won't recognize table field references

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use an UPDATE SQL statement to conditionally populate some table fields based on the value of another field. For some reason, I'm getting an error that says it cannot find the |1 field. I have checked the table reference and spelling of the fields, but can't figure out why it can't find them. The code is (it's the strUpdateProd line that is causing the error):

```
Private Sub btnProduct_Click()

    Dim dlg As FileDialog
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strUpdateProd As String

    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With dlg
        .Title = "Select Audit File to Import"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tblProductImport")
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "Product Import Spec", "tblProductImport", strFileName

    strUpdateProd = "UPDATE [tblProductImport] " _
        & "SET [tblProductImport].[Register] = '" & IIf([tblProductImport].[InvestSplit1] = "R", "RRSP", "TFSA") & "' " _
        & "WHERE [tblProductImport].[HolderID] IS NOT NULL;"

    DoCmd.RunSQL strUpdateProd
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
strUpdateProd = "UPDATE [tblProductImport] " _
    & "SET [tblProductImport].[Register] = IIf([tblProductImport].[InvestSplit1] = 'R', 'RRSP', 'TFSA') " _
    & "WHERE [tblProductImport].[HolderID] IS NOT NULL;"
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Guess I'm still confused about where punctuation is required when building an SQL statement in Access VBA.

Comment: Your original code tried to concatenate a variable "outside" the SQL which [tblProductImport].[InvestSplit1] isn't.